# Two simple mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm a noob when it comes to mysql and php, and just want to ask if I do this correct:

1. I want to SELECT from a table where "lastTurn" is more then 12h. Is this the correct way to do it. I'm most concernt with the 12h time stamp

   `$queryQuit = mysql_query("SELECT match_id, lastTurn FROM active_matches WHERE      matchStatus=0 AND noticeSent < 2 AND lastTurn < NOW() - INTERVAL 12 HOUR");`
2. I use Asihttprequest to send data to the server. If I send an int, do I need to convert it before it goes into the database?

   ```
   //score is an int
   $score = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['score']); 

   //Update a table where the field is an int 
    "UPDATE hiscore SET score=score + '$score' WHERE username='$username'"
   ```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Question 2: yes, convert it to an int (`$score = (int) $_POST['score'];` instead of your escape line) and remove the apostrophes from around `$score` in the `UPDATE` statement.

Comment: Thanks. Is there something that can go wrong with the apostrophes, or is it just unnecessarily?

Comment: It's unnecessary. It'll probably still work, but your database will read it as a string, and then realise it can be converted to a number due to the column type, rather than converting it to a number immediately.

Comment: aha.. So I should skip the apostrophes for int values, and keep it if I know the variable is a string?

Comment: For the avoidance of doubt, the conversion to integer using `(int)` effectively escapes user input - no SQL injection can get past that. But for strings you are quite correct to use the escape function you've used - good to see!

Comment: _So I should skip the apostrophes for int values, and keep it if I know the variable is a string?_ Correct!

Comment: That said, it is better to use the `PDO` approach, so you can use value parameterisation. The _mysql_ module is quite old these days.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10652/discussion-between-user1251004-and-halfer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. This looks correct
2. You need to cast to int if you want to make sure you are saving an integer

Code example:

```
$score = mysql_real_escape_string((int) $_POST['score']);
```

or

```
$score = mysql_real_escape_string(intval($_POST['score']));
```